# jquery version isn't updating

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, rubygems

Why does my app keep telling me I'm using jQuery 1.7.2 from this (I've restarted the server)

```
 $(function(){
    console.log($().jquery);
 });
```

I was using jquery-rails 2.0.2 and that does infact use 1.7.2 however I've updated my gem file to and ran bundle install:

```
gem 'jquery-rails', '~> 2.3.0'
```

and still it's saying im on 1.7.2 when infact it should be 1.10 as shown in the link below:

https://github.com/rails/jquery-rails/blob/master/VERSIONS.md

My IDE is saying the specified version of jquery-rails is not available in SDK 'RVM: ruby-1.9.3-p374 [rails3]'

in app.js I have:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
```

Comment: Check which file you're including in your markup file

Comment: have you tried `bundle update` ?

Comment: Maybe clear your browser cache and try again?

Comment: it was my browser cache...fail